# Error in reading and writing in a txt file in python

Tags: python

When I try to read and write any file like txt it always returns an error

`Expected Type int got string instead`

How to solve this?
here is my code

```
from os import *

def reading(data):
    with open(data , 'r') as op:
        name = op.read()
        op.close()
        return name

def write(data, write):
    with open(data , 'w') as op:
        op.write(str(write))
        op.close()
```

in this code, I want to read a text file so that I have created a function for this which will return the data which is written in a specific file and also it can write any data in that file if we call second one function at first it was not showing any error but now it is showing how can I solve this...

**Error Log**

```
File "data.py", line 15, in add_another_line
    with open(name, 'r') as op:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

**and**

```
File "data.py", line 15, in add_another_line
    with open(name, 'w') as op:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

these are errors

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including the full error message. BTW please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: And also, you don't need to `close` the file object when opening it using `with`, it'll be closed automatically.

Comment: @Pryanshu-Sharma attach the error log

Comment: File "data.py", line 15, in add_another_line
    with open(name , 'r') as op:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Here is error and also sorry about this becouse i am new in stackoverflow thats way i donot know about it

Comment: `from os import *` imports [os.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) as `open`. Don't do that.

Comment: `from os import *` also imports `os.write` as `write`. But then you shadow that when you redefine `write()`. Don't shadow builtin functions or types, and don't do `from os import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error happens because you named your function `write` with the same name as a method ([`os.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.write)), which you imported with `from os import *`.

I suggest to rename your function like this:

```py
import os

def reading(data):
    with open(data , 'r') as op:
        name = op.read()
        op.close()
        return name

def writing(data, myInput):
    with open(data , 'w') as op:
        op.write(str(myInput))
        op.close()
```

Comment: Diong `op.close()` inside the `with open...` context is unnecessary and bad idiom. Could just directly do `return op.read()`

Answer (score 2):

As @Justin Ezequiel mentioned, when you have

```
from os import *
```

it will import `open` function from `os` module and replace the built-in `open` function.
So if you need to use the module, just import the module as it is. And also do not `close` the file object within `with` block

```
from os

def reading(data):
    with open(data , 'r') as op:
        name = op.read()
        return name

def write(data, write):
    with open(data , 'w') as op:
        op.write(str(write))
```

This will work as expected.